# Custom python database logger, having circular import

Tags: python, logging, handler

I am trying to create my own log handler to log to db models, which extends logging.Handler

```
import logging
from logging import Handler
from logger.models import SearchLog

class DBHandler(Handler,object):
    model = None
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(DBHandler, self).__init__()
        mod = __import__(model)
        components = name.split('.')
        for comp in components[1:]:
            mod = getattr(mod, comp)
        self.model = mod

    def emit(self,record):
        log_entry = self.model(level=record.levelname, message=record.msg)
        log_entry.save()
```

and this is the log config:

```
'db_search_log':{
    'level': 'INFO',
    'class': 'db_logger.handlers.DBHandler',
    'model': 'db_logger.models.SearchLog',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
     }
```

however I am getting the follow error, see stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'db_search_log': Unable to configure handler 'db_search_log': 'module' object has no attribute 'handlers'
```

▾

```
db_logger/                                                                                                                                                                                                
    __init__.py                
    __init__.pyc
    handlers.py
    handlers.pyc
    log_handlers.pyc
    models.py
    models.pyc
    router.py
    router.pyc
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Thanks to @istruble pointed out that that is due to circular imports of settings, how can I avoid it and still log to the database models?

Comment: How are you running this? Are you able to start it up with `python -m pdb`, or possibly put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your settings.py and continue, so that you can get a pdb prompt at the point of the error and inspect the state?

Comment: Possibly a circular import of settings.py?  Scroll up 6 lines from this section of the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#custom-logging-configuration

Comment: @istruble yes it's due to circular import, because the log handler uses a model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came up with another actually more canonical way of implementing it using delayed imports, my original problem was trying to import the model inside **init** function:

```
from logging import Handler

class DBHandler(Handler,object):
    model_name = None

    def __init__(self, model=""):
        super(DBHandler,self).__init__()
        self.model_name = model

    def emit(self,record):
        # instantiate the model
        try:
            model = self.get_model(self.model_name)
        except:
            from logger.models import GeneralLog as model

        log_entry = model(level=record.levelname, message=self.format(record))


        log_entry.save()

    def get_model(self, name):
        names = name.split('.')
        mod = __import__('.'.join(names[:-1]), fromlist=names[-1:])
        return getattr(mod, names[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a work around and I admit it looks like a hack, which uses the model injection at actual logging point like this

```
from logging import Handler

class DBHandler(Handler,object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DBHandler, self).__init__()

    def emit(self,record):
        model = record.model
        log_entry = model(level=record.levelname, message=record.msg)
        log_entry.save()
```

and you log it to the correct model by doing this:

```
import logging
import logger.models.TheModel

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info(123, extra={'model':TheModel})
```